# Toxic Christmas Gifts for Riley?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

***What am I?***

> For my prefix I received `ri`. Now I'm insecure.
>
> For my infix I received `ul`. Now I'm gloomy.
>
> For my suffix I received `pe`. Now I don't converse in person.
>
> *Perhaps the gifts aren't to blame... even without them,
> my mood changes like the weather.*

---

***Example: If my word is `hop`, the riddle may go like this:***

> For my prefix I received `s`. Now I spend. *(shop)*
>
> For my infix I received `o`. Now I'm round. *(hoop)*
>
> For my suffix I received `e`. Now I have a wish. *(hope)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are

> sky

so that

> risky, sulky, skype.

and of course

> your mood changes like the weather, by definition of weather.

Answer (score 0):

For my prefix I received ri. Now I'm insecure.

> You are risky

For my infix I received ul. Now I'm gloomy.

> You are sulky

For my suffix I received pe. Now I don't converse in person.

> You have skype

I think you are

> The sky

Comment: Hi Herb and welcome to Puzzling :) This exact answer has already been given by WhatsUp and marked as correct, so there's no need to go adding it again. If you like trying to solve riddles here without checking others' answers, please do at least check them between solving and posting, to be sure your idea hasn't already been given already. Thanks, and Happy Puzzling!